# Volume map a properties file into a webapp inside docker

Tags: java, tomcat, docker, volume

Is it possible to volume map a properties file into the class path of a webapp that has been deployed on tomcat inside a docker container?
When I try doing that it replaces the contents of the root folder for example:

if the v-map is:

> -v < host-folder >/x.properties:< container-path-to-tomcat >/webapps//WEB-INF/classes/x.properties

Then the entire contents of < container-path-to-tomcat >/webapps//WEB-INF/  gets replaced.
Any insights?   The question is whether replacing deployed artifacts inside a container is even possible?

Comment: Either modify the file before deployment or try to add an additional directory to the classpath and modify that one by using a volume

Comment: yeah - thanks.  Thats the approach I will take.  Started thinking about it as I was typing up the question.  Just did not want to change the Dockerfile

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, "volumes" in Docker are supposed to be directories and not single files. This is by design. If possible, put your properties file in a separate directory.

Comment: Docker supports mounting files: https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/volumes/volumes/

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is not related with files but with the workflow of mounting volumes:
The appServer will not expand the WAR file because docker already mounted the volume with the same directory name.

This makes any sense?